# 3 Column table using divs (to act like a <table>)

Tags: html, css-tables

I need a 3 column table using div's.

It must be fluid and cover 100% of the width of the window.

The left column should be 50% of the width with the other two columns being 20% each and the remaining space used for cell padding.

Additionally I need to make sure that when a cell contents get word wrapped, every cell in that row is adjusted so that the heights match. (Act like it would using the `<table>` tag). I would like each row and column to have a border so every line of the table is clear. I hope someone can help.

I have looked and looked for the solution but so far it has eluded me.

Comment: show your code of what you have so far

Comment: You should use the web to search for specific problems you are having while coding.  If you want to make a table out of DIV's in HTML, you should probably start with a tutorial teaching HTML and CSS.  What you are asking is very simple and shows you have little or no experience writing HTML and CSS code.  This forum is not a place to have entire code written for you

Comment: "I need" "It must be" "should be" - Demanding are we now? You're not going to get far with this attitude asking for help.

Comment: @user3530168 you can mark my answer as accepted if it helped, if not you can leave a comment.  People do spend time on here helping , you can use the up votes and marking answers as accepted to help the person that answered and to help future visitors to show them it answered the question

Answer (score 3):

See it working here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3esw6/)

```
<div class="table">
   <div class="cell"></div>
   <div class="cell"></div>
   <div class="cell"></div>
</div>



.table{
position:relative;  /*so children div can use 100% height and not go over */
width:100%; /* as long as this div's parent is body it will take up whole screen */
height:250px; /*make whatever you want */
padding:8px; /* will make that spacing you wanted */
}


.table .cell{
width:20%;
height:100%;
background-color:#bbb;
display:inline-block; /*so they display inline */
}

.table .cell:first-of-type{
width:50%;
height:100%;
background-color:#ddd;
}
```